# bash loop through masterfile to determine how many occurrences are in specific folder

Tags: bash, while-loop, grep, cat

I have a masterfile (master.txt) which contains multiple 4-7 character strings on each row (~38213 rows large). I also have a folder of data which contains  multiple files (file1, file2, etc.) that also contains multiple 4-7 character strings.

The question is, I know that if I cd to the working directory, and type

```
cat * | grep -c 'value'
```

I will get the number of occurrences of 'value' in all of the files in the current directory. What if I want to loop through 'value' which is being read from a masterfile? I know that with the 'while read' function, something can be done, but combining the two does not work. For example:

```
masterfile="path/to/masterfile/master.txt"
foldername="path/to/folder"

cd foldername

while IFS='' read line || [[ -n "$line" ]]
do
echo cat * | grep -c $line >> /path/to/output/file.txt
done < $masterfile
```

But I get 0's. Any thoughts?

Comment: You have an extra `echo` in front of it for some reason. Just remove it

Comment: Don't you have any error messages on your terminal (file not found, issued by grep)? You say that each line in masterfile contain multiple words; I guess you want to search for each of those words, not for the whole line, right? A sample (a few lines) of masterfile and your other files would be welcome, as well as the expected result.

Comment: that other guy's response was all that was needed!

Also, putting a -w within the grep also matches the exact word. For example, if I was searching for '400' but there were instances of 'D400', then that would count as well.

Now the question is how do I echo out a line: "$line has occurred n number of times" (which was what I initially wanted, but didn't realize the solution to this problem was so easy!)